# Three.js Transform Controls - move programmatically

Tags: three.js

Could anyone help with a quick description of how to move the Three.js transform controls programmatically. I would like to test changing values dynamically and also set bounds when moving manually.

i.e http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: When using the transform controls like in the example provided I would like to know how to move the controllers in js instead of using a mouse for testing purposes. I am assuming I will have to apply a new matrix to THREE.TransformControls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "move the Transform Controls" you can move the object. The TransformControls will update itself.

In the example:

```
controller = scene.children[4];
box = controller.object;
box.translateX(20); 
// ... Other transformations
render();   //You have to rerender the scene
```

To set bounds, you have to check the conditions after moving, adding an EventListener.

```
t.addEventListener('change', functionCheckBounds)
```